# How to style &amp;

Tags: html, css

How do I style the &amp; in the below html?

```
<a>Ian</a>
&amp;
<a>Jim</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap it with a span instead, e.g.

```
<a>Ian</a>
<span>&amp;</span>
<a>Jim</a>
```

Then of course, add a rule to the span, or preferabbly add a class to it then add rules to it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot style some random character if it's not wrapped around a tag.

Of course that character is inserted into the parent element, but you cannot style that `&amp;` alone.

You need to wrap it in a tag, for example a span tag, give it a class or an ID, so that you can write a CSS rule to be able to target that element.

```
<span class="amp">&amp;</span>
```

Then in the CSS

```
span.amp {
   /* your rule here */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two thoughts:

1) Wrap it in something that can be styled
2) Style its parent element, let it inherit

Can we see more surrounding html?

Answer (score 0):

Add another tag, or style the container which contains all three elements.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following HTML:

```
<p>
  <a>Ian</a>
  &amp;
  <a>Jim</a>
</p>
```

You can just style it like:

```
p { color: red; }
p a { color: black; }
```

Which would make the & red

Answer (score 0):

Create a style that targets the element that wraps the example that you posted. Then override it for the anchors if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- style the parent of these elements and override what you need in the `a` tag
- add a `span` around the `&amp;` to style just that.